# How can i create a string from this a  text?

Tags: c#, escaping

I have this text:

```
<span class="message-text">
```

I want to add it to a string for example: string s = 
The problem is that message-text is already between ""
And i want that all of it all the  wil be a string.

How can i do it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you clarify quite a bit more? It's already a string - I guess - but I'm just not understanding what you want. Please ***edit*** the question to do so.

Comment: so the question is, if I may rephrase it - "How do I escape the double-quote character." ?

Comment: Mike i want to put this line in a string variable. "message-text" seems like a string but i want to take all the <span class="message-text"> and put it in a string so for example string t will contain this line as a complete string one string. But the "" in the message-text make the problem from creating a string of all the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you mean but ima try

first add `runat="server"` to your span, and give it an ID

```
<span runat="server" ID="mySpan"></span>
```

Then in code behind

```
string s = "message-text";

mySpan.Attributes.Add("class", s);
```

output in html will be

```
<span runat="server" ID="mySpan" class="message-text">
```

or you mean

```
string mySpan = "<span class=\"message-text\">";
```

or

```
string mySpan = "<span class='message-text'>";
```

Comment: Of of those is what you are looking for :)

Comment: No problem, i think for all the ones that worked for you can give a vote up :)

Comment: @JohnnBlade I like your gold badge

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do

```
string myString = "<span class=\"message-text\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string str = "<span class='message-text'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

shilld your symbols by `\` or use verbatim strings

`@""""; //"`

`"\""' //""`

Answer (score 0):

backslash, \ is used to escape double quote and many other characters... So you could write your line of code as:

```
String str = "<span class=\"message-text\">"
```

Read more about escape character [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Answer (score -1):

```
string l = "<span class=\"message-text\">";
```

see here for more details : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx